# How to order exceptions in this try-throw-catch code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get on the screen: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, but I don't know how to order the catch(s) in my program. Is it possible to get this output by ordering the catches? Can you please explain how it works? I searched in many forums, but I have found nothing about that. Thank you so much.

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class My_Exception : public exception {};
class something {};
void func1() { cout << "1" << endl; throw exception(" no t h ing "); }
void func2() { cout << "2" << endl; throw string(" 12345 "); }
void func3() { cout << "3" << endl; throw out_of_range(" abcde "); }
void func4() { cout << "4" << endl; throw ios::failure(" i o s "); }
void func5() { cout << "5" << endl; throw My_Exception(); }
void func6() { cout << "6" << endl; throw something(); }
void func7() { cout << "7" << endl; throw logic_error(" t r u e "); }
int main() {
try {
func1(); func2(); func3();
func4(); func5(); func6();
func7();
}
catch (My_Exception) {/*1*/ }
catch (exception) {/*2*/ }
catch (logic_error) {/*3*/ }
catch (string) {/*4*/ }
catch (...) {/*5*/ }
catch (out_of_range) {/*6*/ }
catch (ios::failure) {/*7*/ }
catch (something) {/*8*/ }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the order of catch instructions in main function, in order to print :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
if you run this code, you will see just the number "1"

Comment: @immibis Probably those sentences that end with a question mark...

Comment: Catching a C++ exception doesn't make the execution resume at the throwing point. As I recall Microsoft argued for resumable exceptions during the standardization process, but nobody else wanted that. The low level Windows SEH exceptions are resumable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You need to read more on exceptions. After the call to `func1()` an exception is thrown, so the control is transferred to the first `catch` block that matches the type of the thrown exception. The rest of the `catch` block **is skipped**.

Comment: @ gldraphael : so is it impossible to do it in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you throw an exception, the code in `try` block ends its execution. The program executes corresponding `catch` block, and then continues to execute lines that come after that. A `catch` block is only executed after you throw an exception.

If you want to continue execution after catching an exception, you should use multiple `try` blocks. The following code prints 1 and 2.

```
void func1() { cout << "1" << endl; throw exception(" no t h ing "); }
void func2() { cout << "2" << endl; throw string(" 12345 "); }
try{
    func1();
    cout << "this is not printed" << endl;
}
catch(exception){
    // This is executed after throw
}
catch(string){
    // This is not executed
}

try{
    func2();
}
catch(exception){
    // This is not executed
}
catch(string){
    // This is executed after throw
}
```

Comment: That was so helpfull... Thank you so much... So there is no way to do that with one try block? right?

Comment: @Joe Yes, you need multiple try blocks.

Comment: @Joe Order of catch blocks does not matter, if your exception classes are not related to each other. However, in your code you are catching `exception`, and also some classes that are inherited from `exception` (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm ). This means if your `catch(exception)` stays in its current location, it will be reached before `catch(logic_error)` or `catch(out_of_range)`, and code in those blocks is never executed; they execute code in the `catch(exception)` block instead. So you should move that block more down.

Comment: You also have `catch(...)`, which catches everything. Any catch block that comes after it will be never executed. So `catch(...)` should always be the last. Only one catch block is executed for each `throw`.

Comment: @Joe You should also move `catch (logic_error)` before `catch(exception)`. After that it should work. Here you can find list of standard exceptions (which have been inherited from `exception` class): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/

Answer (score 5):

Read [more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/841108) about C++11. Spend a few days reading a good book on [*Programming in C++*](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/)

This [`try`...`catch` block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) explanation tells that

> When an exception of type E is thrown by any statement in compound-statement, it is matched against the types of the formal parameters T of each catch-clause in handler-seq, *in the order* in which the catch clauses are listed.

hence you might want to order your `catch` block by putting the most frequent exceptions first (but in practice, the order does not matter much, as long as there is no overlap between `catch`....; if there is an overlap then put the most precise `catch` clause first).

Since in [`<stdexcept>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) the `std::logic_error` is a subclass of `std::exception` you should put `catch(logic_error)` (the more precise) before `catch(exception)` (the less precise but overlapping catch)

Comment: @Angew: done (first link)